# Static initialization block differences between Java 13 and Java 8; with different IDE versions (netbeans 8.2 vs outdated apache netbeans 12)

Tags: java

The only discernable difference between these two programs is the Java version.

The question is: what on earth is going on?

This image is proof that both programs contain exactly the same code, while producing different results.

[image]

here is the code:

```java
static int x = 10;

static {
    x = x + 10;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));
    System.out.println(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

- LEFT side is using the old netbeans distribution.
- RIGHT side is using the apache netbeans IDE.
- LEFT side is using jdk8 (see image)
- RIGHT side is using jdk13 (see image)

Based on the comments:
jdk13 is EOL ... but some people are unable to reproduce it while using jdk13.

The question is: what's causing this?

- netbeans distribution?
- borked jdk
- ... some setting in the apache IDE?
- ... the stars being out of alignemnt?
- etc.

Comment: It highlights the fact that it's the same code.

Comment: On my machine, I get the same result for Java 8 and Java 16 and Java 17.  The result is 20.  (Which matches my understanding of what it should be.)

Comment: looks like a specific bug for 13....

Comment: Well ... maybe ... or maybe you somehow have a borked JDK installation.  Either way, Java 13 is EOL.  You (and anyone else reading this!) should at this point be using Java 11 or Java 17.  Java 12 through 16 are all EOL.

Comment: I have 13.0.2 installed on my machine - can't reproduce. (It outputs 20 as expected). Maybe try to rebuild your project or something - you may be running a different piece of code.

Comment: @assylias I rebuilt it a few times....

Comment: I have adoptopenjdk v13.0.2+8

Comment: Can you compile and run both programs without an IDE? is the result still the same?

Comment: Yea ... it could be that one of the IDE's is running a stale .class file ... i.e. one that doesn't match the source code that you are looking at.  Note that the actual behavior here (static initialization) is implemented in the JVM itself.

Comment: @StephenC; @assylias ;@Lino Compilation of the source code through command line javac & java jdk 3 bundle execution yields different (and also correct) results from what the IDE executes.

Comment: I just grabbed the `adoptopenjdk:13.0.2_8-jre-openj9-0.18.0-bionic` Docker image, which seems to match the AdoptOpenJDK version you are running. Compiled the code and ran it, and the output was **20**. Therefore, I cannot reproduce it.

Comment: While we're at the subject — you shouldn't use `Date` anymore. It's outdated, archaic and antique. Also, it's [troublesome](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1969442/507738). Use classes from `java.time` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ANSWER: Underlying problem determined to exist in IDE's compilation/build/execution routine.**

Reinstall and update IDE, adoption of non-EOL JDK.

[image]

Also, I did not import existing IDE settings.

Comment: Seems like a bug in whatever compiler your IDE is using. The JLS is rather clear on the order of execution [JLS 12.4.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1): "Next, execute either the class variable initializers and static initializers of the class, or the field initializers of the interface, **in textual order**, as though they were a single block."